# Extracting values from text file using autohotkey

Tags: file, extract, autohotkey, readline, substr

I have a small text file that I would like to extract some values using autohotkey.

Example of text file's content:

```
  Date: 2014-12-02 12:06:47
 Study: G585.010.411
 Image: 6.24
 Tlbar: 2.60
 Notes: 0.74
```

My current code:

```
FileReadLine, datetime, C:\File.txt, 1
datedsp := SubStr(datetime, 7)
Sleep 500
FileReadLine, study, C:\File.txt, 2
studydsp := SubStr(study, 7)
Sleep 500
FileReadLine, image, C:\File.txt, 3
imgdsp := SubStr(image, 7)
Sleep 500
FileReadLine, notes, C:\File.txt, 5
notesdsp := SubStr(notes, 7)
Sleep 500

MsgBox %datedsp%
MsgBox %studydsp%
MsgBox %imgdsp%
MsgBox %notesdsp%
```

All I want to do is to grab the value of each of those lines and assign it to variables. For example, *studydsp* value would be G58500411, *imagedsp* value would be 6.24, *datedsp* value would be 2014-12-02 12:06:47.

**Is there anyway to achieve this in a better way?**

**Possible issues with this code:**

1. I am unable to get the string from the date line perhaps due to a space at
   the beginning(?)
2. I can't get the SubStr value of either date (refer to 1st issue) or
   study (perhaps because of special characters?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FileRead](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileRead.htm) and [RegExMatch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm)

```
var:="
(
 Date: 2014-12-02 12:06:47
Study: G585.010.411
Image: 6.24
Tlbar: 2.60
Notes: 0.74
)"

;~ FileRead, var, C:\file.txt
pos:=1
while pos := RegExMatch(var, "\s?(.*?):(.*?)(\v|\z)", m, pos+StrLen(m))
    %m1% := m2

msgbox % "Date holds " date
    . "`nStudy holds " Study
    . "`nImage holds " Image
    . "`nTlbar holds " Tlbar
    . "`nNotes holds " Notes
```

Just remove the var part and uncomment the fileread line, at least thats one way to do it to :)

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same as @blackholyman's answer, but using an object based approach by building a value map:

```
fileCont = 
(
Date: 2014-12-02 12:06:47
Study: G585.010.411
Image: 6.24
Tlbar: 2.60
Notes: 0.74
)

valueMap := {}

; Alternatively, use: Loop, Read, C:\file.txt
Loop, Parse, fileCont, `r`n
{
    RegExMatch(A_LoopField, "(.*?):(.*)", parts)
    ; Optionally make keys always lower case:
    ; StringLower, parts1, parts1
    valueMap[Trim(parts1)] := Trim(parts2)

}

msgbox %   "Date = "    valueMap["Date"]
         . "`nImage = " valueMap["Image"]

; We can also iterate over the map
out := ""
for key, val in valueMap
{
    out .= key "`t= " val "`n"
}
msgbox % out
```